# Set default values to null values in an object

Tags: typescript

I want to change `null` to another value in an object, eg:

```js
interface MyObject {
  id: number;
  name: string | null;
  age?: number | null;
  address?: string | null;
}

const myObj: MyObject = { id: 1, name: null, age: 30 };

// assignDefaults is my function
const newMyObj = assignDefaults(myObj, {
  name: 'Default Name',
  address: 'New York',
});

console.log(newMyObj); // desired output：{ id: 1, name: 'Default Name', age: 30, address: 'New York' }
```

How to realize function `assignDefaults`?

Note: Only set value when null.

Comment: ```function assignDefaults(original: MyObject, defaults: Partial<MyObject>) {
  return {...original, ...defaults};
}```

Comment: this will overwrite the original with default value

Comment: @OyinladeDemola Yes, it's not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate over the properties of your default object and juse the [`??=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment) operator to assign the values to the original object. Using     `foo.xy ??= bar.xy` will only do the assignment, if `foo.xy` is "nullish" (ie `null` or `undefined`). Thus it will not replace existing properties.

The `//@ts-ignore` here is necessary, because TS is not (yet?) capable ensuring the correctness when using `keyof` on a generic type (what `for .. in` loop implicitly does). But it's still safe here, because, `Partial<T>` cannot have any keys that don't exist in `T`.

```
interface MyObject {
  id: number;
  name: string | null;
  age?: number | null;
  address?: string | null;
}

const myObj: MyObject = { id: 1, name: null, age: 30 };
const def: Partial<MyObject> = { name: "foo", address: "bar", age: 0 }

function assignDefaults<T>(obj: T, def: Partial<T>): T {
  //create a new result object to avoid manipulating the existing object
  //if you want to amend in place you can skip this
  let res = {...obj}
  for (let k in def) {  //iterate over all properties in the default object
    //@ts-ignore
    res[k] ??= def[k];  //assign the default value only if the orignal property is null or undefined
  }
  return res;
}


let obj = assignDefaults(myObj, def);
console.log(obj);
```

Running the above example for instance in [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8DyAjAVhBMZAbwChllgATALmRAFcBbbaAbnPriYjoGcwUUAHNkAH3oMANlI4U4wiAH46jFtHGSZc5HCpUoEPnxXIBQkKImNtpAL6lSCAPYgByJljx0MOfIWQAXhJKWmQARgAaLh5VaSlohV5kAGYABmQ7Dhc3IioIGDoABTgoMGA4KQAeXzwCMAA+IJCQbmSAIhhnZ3bE-UNjOnbsUt7dRToAJgBWTMcYBhBCYFddY2BhEAARArhpMD4qgBUGgApnb2Qj6PzC5BKyiuqTgEo6I5JOKQgiAebiAB0QIuuAcFC6UGQp2+RAA1pQQMhbi9PhQKAB6dEAAQOAFoNiBnIZOBQBgBtWEAXWQSiUwVuFMpOjByEMYAYUERAw4DkcMOQIOacHWmx28H2fFOnj8NwKL2yrj4zm+AKkzmE5zw8scQA) will show you that it repalces the `name: null` from the original object, but keeps the `age: 30`

Comment: Thx bro your answer is helpful. But I wonder if it's better to use cloneDeep when create a new result object?

Comment: depends on your type ... If it's not nested and only contains primitive values (like string or number) like you have in your example  there is no need for deep cloneing. If it can be nested, it might be necessary ...

Comment: Also be aware, this only sets defaults on the first level. Ie if you have a nested structure and you have some missing values nested in an object, this wont't be amended here ...

Comment: It's ok because I just want check it's properties

Answer (score -1):

You can first slice out the null key then use the spread oprator to join the default and object

```
interface MyObject {
  id: number;
  name: string | null;
  age?: number | null;
  address?: string | null;
}

function assignDefaults<T>(obj: T, defaults: Partial<T>): T {
    

const newMyObj = Object.fromEntries(
 Object.entries(obj).filter(([_, value]) => value !== null)
) as MyObject;

  return { ...defaults, ...newMyObj };
}

const myObj: MyObject = { id: 1, name: null, age: 30 };

const newMyObj = assignDefaults(myObj, {
  name: 'Default Name',
  address: 'New York',
});

console.log(newMyObj);
```

Comment: you are aware, that your `assignDefaults` function is completely ignoring the `obj` you are passing as parameter and always is taking the values from the completely unrelated `myObj` object you create (for whatever reasons) in the function? Furthermore, what is the purpose of the generic `<T>` if you (again) completely ignore it? Ie there should be no reference to the `MyObject` type inside the `assignDefaults` function ...

Answer (score -1):

```
interface MyObject {
     id: number;
     name: string | null;
     age?: number | null;
     address?: string | null;
}

const myObj: MyObject = { id: 1, name: null, age: 30 };
function assignDefaults(a:MyObject, d:object)
{
    var r = a as MyObject;
    for (const k in d) {
        r[k] = a[k] ?? d[k];
    }
    return r;
}
// assignDefaults is my function
const newMyObj = assignDefaults(myObj, {
    name: 'Default Name',
    address: 'New York',
});

console.log(newMyObj) // desired output：{ id: 1, name: 'Default Name', age: 30, address: 'New York' }
```

As an output:

> (4) {id: 1, name: "Default Name", age: 3...}

Comment: What is the purpose of `var r = a as MyObject;` if you are manipulating `a[k] = ...` anyways?

Comment: typo, what I meant is `r[k] = a[k] ?? d[k]`

Comment: Still, what is the purpose of this object `r`? It is not a new object, it's just giving the object `a` and additional name. Ie, `r` and `a` are pointing to the very same object in memory. Thus, doing `r[k] = ...` is equivalent to `a[k] = ...` and at the end of this method, `a` and `r` will look the same (because they are in fact the very same object). Also you don't need to do `r = a as MyObject` because `a` is already of type `MyObject` thus, doing `r = a` will lead to the same result.

Comment: And last but not least: Your code does not not compile ... because your `d` is of type `object` and not `MyObject`,  typescript cannot assure, that any key `k` of `d` can be used as a key in class `MyObject`. Nothing prevents anybody from doing `assignDefaults(myobj, {"foo": "bar"})` ie passing a property that isn't defined in the `MyObject` type in the default object ...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).